# Overfull \hbox in Longtable

Tags: longtable, textwidth

I'm trying to get rid of the error in my Longtable

> Overfull \hbox (1.19998pt too wide) in alignment at lines 6--10

This is my MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth -2\tabcolsep\relax}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth -2\tabcolsep\relax}|}
\hline
Test & Test\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Why do I get this error? In my understanding both columns of the longtable should take exactly 50% of the textwidth minus the left and right tabcolsep.

Comment: The message is actually not an error message, but "just" a warning message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the calculation of the usable columnwidth, you are correctly substracting the whitespace padding. However, you have failed to take into account the widths of the three vertical rules that are present in the table as well. The width of these vertical rules is governed by the parameter `\arrayrulewidth`; its default value is `0.4pt` in most document classes. Observe that `3*0.4pt=1.2pt`, which is extremely close to the reported overfullness of `1.19998pt`. (In fact, 1.19998 and 2 *are* the same up to a rounding error.)

What to do? Piece of cake! Just change both instances of

```
p{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth -2\tabcolsep\relax
```

to

```
p{\dimexpr 0.5\textwidth -2\tabcolsep -1.5\arrayrulewidth\relax
```

Why `1.5\arrayrulewidth`? Because 2*1.5 = 3 = # of vertical rules in the `longtable`.

Comment: Wow, thank your very much for your help and detailed explanation :-)